# Should we have a nexus-7-2013 tag?

Tags: discussion

Perhaps we can rename [nexus-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7) to [nexus-7-2012](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7-2012), and create a new [nexus-7-2013](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7-2013) for the 2nd generation tablet.

Comment: Or handle it like we do with the Samsung Galaxy 7 tab, and just create a `nexus-7-2` tag? That would at least be consistent.

Comment: @Izzy Yeah, that seems better for consistency.

Comment: All the references I see when specifically about one or the other references the year.

Comment: Does anyone know what the Apple SE does now that Apple have dropped version numbers for the iPad?

Comment: @GAThrawn It seems they only have 1 tag: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad

Comment: Do we really need separate tags? Do we have that many questions about either Nexus 7?

Comment: @AlEverett - As the guy who's been running the tag cleanup efforts, I would think you'd recognize the benefit of having specific tags ready to go before they become seriously needed so users can either tag their questions properly or so someone can correct them right off the bat rather than having to retag dozens of questions at once.

Comment: Yes, and by-and-large we _don't_ need _device-specific_ tags.

Comment: @AlEverett Would you like to add that as an answer, so at least we can all vote on something and have a general concensus?

Comment: For what it's worth, a refreshed Galaxy Note 10.1 was just announced, and it's being referred to by the year (2014).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, we don't *need* device-specific tags. They lead to overuse. It's pretty rare for an issue that someone is facing to actually be specific to their device. (People should use tags to help categorize their *issue*, not their *device*.)

I've not seen evidence that there's an overabundance of questions where the distinction between the original Nexus 7 and the newer (2013) model is in anyway important.

So, I say: No, we don't need a new tag, nor to rename the old one.

Answer (score 11):

I think it should be [nexus-7-2012](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7-2012) and [nexus-7-2013](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7-2013).

Here's my reasoning:

1. [Nexus 7 (2012)](https://play.google.com/store/devices/details/Nexus_7_2012_16GB?id=nexus_7_16gb) is what Google themselves calls the old device on the Play Store.
2. The wikipedia articles on the devices are [Nexus 7 (2012 version)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282012_version%29) and [Nexus 7 (2013 version)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_%282013_version%29).
3. [A Google search shows 102 million hits](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22nexus%207%202013%22) for "Nexus 7 2013", versus only [33.8 million for "Nexus 7 2"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22nexus%207%202%22), and [a mere 3.5 million for "Nexus 7 2nd generation"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22nexus%207%202nd%20generation%22) so the former is clearly the more common naming.

Comment: The reasoning sounds convincing even to me :) Maybe I'm over-cautious just because I'm not owning a single Nexus.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment on the question itself, if the differences between those generations justify separate tags, we should handle that similar to [samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7) for two reasons:

1. consistency
2. easier handling (nobody will stick to the year in the tag, most will even confuse it)

From the [samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7) tag wiki: *It is the successor to the original Galaxy Tab 7.0* – so we have the same issue here.

so IMHO we should keep the [nexus-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7) tag as-is, and (if necessary) just add a [nexus-2-7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-2-7) (though I wonder if it shouldn't be `nexus-7-2` for "Nexus 7, 2nd generation", and `samsung-galaxy-tab-7-2` respective).

Comment: Nexus-7-2 makes more sense than Nexus-2-7 to me

Comment: To me as well; but the same applies to the existing galaxy tab tag.

Comment: The reason the GT one is `galaxy-tab-2-7` is because that is the *actual name* of the device ([Galaxy Tab 2 7.0](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab/GT-P3113TSYXAR)). The Nexus 7 2 is not a device, and neither is the Nexus 2 7. `nexus-7-2013` seems like it makes the most sense from that standpoint.

Comment: What about `nexus-7-2gen`?

Comment: @Flow I guess the "gen" suffix might be a bit confusing as well. Though I know we're talking about "second generation" here, it took me a second to take it for such (first thought was "genesis", don't ask me why). Do we really need a suffix? If so, what about `nexus-7-2nd` or `nexus-7-v2`? Looks a little more intuitive to me :)

Comment: @eldarerathis I'm afraid latest in 2014 confusion begins if you take year numbers. People will remember they bought the device in 2013 and use that tag for their 1st gen device. For others with the 2nd gen it seems that long ago, they might think it was 2012. And the 3rd group just pickst the first tag popping up, being completely confused. Add a year more (2015), and guess what will be then...

Answer (score 0):

Being afraid the year-tagging may lead to confusion, another alternative would be [nexus-7-2nd](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nexus-7-2nd) for the 2<sup>nd</sup> generation. Quoting my reasons from the comments on my other answer:

- People will remember they bought the device in 2013 and use that tag for their 1st gen device.
- For others with the 2nd gen it seems that long ago, they might think it was 2012.
- And the 3rd group just pickst the first tag popping up, being completely confused.
- Add a year more (2015), plus maybe a 3<sup>rd</sup> generation, and confusion will be even bigger.

`nexus-7-gen2` (or, as Flow put it, `nexus-7-2gen`) would IMHO still be better than a year "numbering" for given reasons.