# Split up the Moto X tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's recently come to my attention that there are two different generations of the Moto X, thanks to [TomG's suggested edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63753).  I would assume that these devices are pretty different.  Should we split them up?  What should we name the tags?

Comment: If we're going to do that, how about splitting [tag:nexus-7] too?

Comment: IMHO, we should do some researches first (based on device spec & features, and based on questions posted here) to know the differences between generations, then decide if it is worth the tag splitting. Also, [tag:motorola-moto-g].

Answer (score 2):

No.

We've discussed this sort of thing in the past ([Should we have a nexus-7-2013 tag?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1581/should-we-have-a-nexus-7-2013-tag)) but  decided not to do it.

The devices don't deviate that much. Plus, by and large, we shouldn't *need* device-specific tags. Most questions that use such tags are applicable to most (if not all) devices. There's more difference based on the version of the OS and/or the OEM skin (HTC Sense, Samsung Touchwiz, etc.)